# Setup is unable to proceed due to the absence of .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, sharepoint-2013

When you try to install below setup on your system  
 **Microsoft Office Web Application** or 
  **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013 Setup** or  
 
 **SharePoint Server 2013 Setup**  
  
 on a computer that has the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 or 4.6.1 installed (specially on Windows 10) , you will receive the following error message:

```
Setup is unable to proceed due to the following error(s):

This product requires Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5
```

I had a tough time resolving this issue so I am going to share my solution, Please drop your answer if you had faced the same issue and had overcome with the better solution.

Comment: It's a helpful fix **[setup unable to proceed: This Product Requires Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/this-product-requires-microsoft-net-framework-4-5-sharepoint-2013-setup-failed/)**

Answer (score 1):

This solution is basically for those who has windows 10 operation system and 
I assumed you guys have already tried un installing the .NET Framework 4.6 or 4.6.1 using below tools without any success

```
Programs and Features

.NET Framework Cleanup
```

As windows 10 comes with inbuilt .NET Framework so uninstalling these softwares with the help of above tool will not help you and the 
problem will remain there.

Note: Below is the solution of development enviornments only as this is a hack which is not recommended on prod servers, I am assuming your development
enviornment is setup on Windows 10 OS.

[image: Regedit for .Net version change]

1. Run regedit.exe as administrator
2. click on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework
   Setup\NDP\
3. At this point you will see two folders v4 and v4.0
4. rightclick on v4, select option to export and save it on you
   local(you may need it if something goes off the expectation)
5. Right-click the v4 node select Permissions -> Advanced -> Change ->
   select the admin account or the account you are using, in my case it
   is "Users (Lenovo-PC\Users)"
6. Tick "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects", and click OK
7. Now go through each node under v4 (in my case there are two sub
       folders "Client" and "Full" and they have their subfolders also):
8. Right-click on each and every node under v4 wherever you see the
   "Version" Key present on the right side window.

   - Set your admin account to have Full Control and click OK.
   - Change the Version value from 4.6.x to 4.5.x (in my case I changed it
     from 4.6.01038 -> 4.5.5150)

Now run the setup and hopefully the installation will get complete without any error.

- Again open the regedit and go to the same location :
- click on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework
  Setup\NDP\
- rightclick on v4 and revert back the version you changed earlier.

or

- Find the exported .reg file from local you saved in the previous step
  and double-click it
- Confirm Yes to import it back to the registry
- Reboot and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released Hotfix(KB 3087184) for the issue. Please check the below link

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/09/14/sharepoint-2013-installer-now-supports-net-framework-4-6-and-above/

KB 3087184 link for download 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3087184

Hope it helps someone..

Comment: Just adding links as answers can make some problems such as broken links, content changing. So it would be great if you can state the complete answer in here

Comment: Added the HotFix KB number and Downlaod link. Thanks for the valuable inputs.